# Is it possible to sign an Ethereum transaction when you only have the account address?

Tags: wallets, signature, ico, polkadot

I need to sign & verify an message on Ethereum, but my problem is that I only have my account address. When I try to use for instance MyCrypto it requires another type of wallet. I have tried other apps but none seems to allow for signing based on solely the Account address. Does anyone have any tips if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can't sign anything without the private key. That's the foundation of the whole blockchain cryptocurrency - if you could sign with just an address it would be a huge security issue.

Comment: Lauri is crisp, of course he is right. I add for you the following: the owner of that account is not you, but the person who know the private key. If you can, move your money to a normal wallet as soon as you can using the account provider facilities.

Answer (score 0):

As Lauri says it is not possible to sign it. My problem was that I participated in the Polkadot ICO without an Ethereum wallet, I used some web pages or something. But after looking through my files I found an JSON file having my ethereum address and various other data. When I opened this file with MyCrypto I was finally able to sign my Ethereum transaction.